# To init, execute and commit better in PostgreSQL with Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, data-structures, schema

Code which I used with PostgeSQL 9.4 and Python 2.7.9

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

def init_pg94_from_sql_file(filename, connection):
    ...
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(...)    
    connection.commit()     
    cursor.close()

def store_values_to_pg94(fileHeader, file_size, eventStarts, eventEnds, connection): 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(...);
    connection.commit()     
    cursor.close()

def(main):
...
    conn_string = "dbname=detector_development user=postgres"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    init_pg94_from_sql_file("12.7.2015.sql", conn)
    store_values_to_pg94(fileHeader, file_size, eventStarts, eventEnds, conn)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

where you see that

- cursor is initiated, executed and commited in each function
- in the main, everything once again committed, and connection closed

I think there can be much duplicates here, because writing to disk by commit in every function sounds to be inefficient. 
Also closing things three times sounds too inefficient.

How can you handle the cursor initialization and commits better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors are lightweight. Closing a cursor is releasing unused memory. In a database connection every transaction should be commited. Commit every task. The efficiency is part of the database's job. If non-commited data is written to disk or when commited data is written, is not your concern.

Comment: So I should close cursor and commit at the end of each function which are using my database connection?

Comment: treat closing cursor and commit separately.   you should close the cursor when you're done with the statement.   you should commit at the end of a transaction, with a transaction being a set of 1 or more statements that have to all succeed or have non-succeed.

Comment: @Gary I close my cursor after all executes of one function at the end of the function. Is this what you mean by *done with statement*. Statement = function?

Comment: Do your functions ever get called by other functions?  The classic (and unrealistic) transaction example is the bank transfer.  increase balance on one account and reduce it on the other.   You may have a function to reduce balance and a function to increase, which together get called from a transfer function.  In that case you wouldn't want to commit in either the increase/reduce function.